# How long should snails be cooked?

Tags: french-cuisine

I used to love the French snails, straight out of the oven in a heavy garlic sauce. Simple question: how long should they be in the oven and at what temperature?

Anybody know what's in the garlic sauce?

Comment: [French' cooking week](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1296/its-french-cuisine-time-ask-great-questions-enter-to-win-a-prize)

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, snails are removed from the shell and simmered for an hour or so in stock or bouillon. Then they are placed back in the shell with a little of the stock, and the shell is 'sealed' with butter, which is usually flavoured with garlic, parsley and shallots.

They are then roasted in a hot oven until the butter has just melted.

Answer (score 0):

Open the can of snails. Rinse very well. Repeat. Pat dry and put them into an escargot baking dish or into the snail shells. Fill with herbed garlic butter and bake on a sheet pan for 8-10 minutes at 425F when the butter is bubbling and browned. Don't forget some thin sliced baguette spread with the same herb butter and toasted for about 2-3 minutes. Garnish with a lemon wedge. I like a a nice cold Pinot Gris from Oregon with this dish.